# How to keep expanded SearchView on the right side of ActionBar (while using custom icon)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, searchview

My question is closely related to [SearchView wrong alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255315/searchview-wrong-alignment) and [SearchView positions when expanded in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316113/searchview-positions-when-expanded-in-actionbar) but the answers posted there do not work.

So, I'm using a [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) in the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/navi_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
   />
```

It looks like this by default (top-right corner, next to overflow menu):

[image]

Problem is, when expanded, **I'd like the SearchView to stay on the right**, but instead, it moves to the left edge, next to home button (app icon).

I tried changing `showAsAction` to either of these ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271539/56285)):

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:showAsAction="always"
```

...And that does fix the alignment when expanded, but **the custom icon is lost** when in collapsed state:

[image]

Also, stuff like `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` on the menu `<item>` have no effect.

Any ideas?

I'm targetting Android 4.0 and above:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, I found a way:

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, after the standard menu inflating stuff, set 
[`ActionBar.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html) with `Gravity.RIGHT` for the `SearchView` instance:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {        
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    // ...

    // Find the SearchView; make it aligned to right, also in expanded mode:
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    search.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
}
```

(In the menu definition XML, I still use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`.)

Now the SearchView opens on the right, in the same place where the icon is, and the custom icon is still in use.

Comment: One might assume that `android:gravity="right"` on the SearchView `<item>` in menu XML would achieve this too, but at least on my test devices it does not.

Comment: Yes, it works fine on Android 4.0+. Do you get an exception with this approach? Consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Try editing this line

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```

to:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

it will align the edittext to the right.

Comment: By reading the *whole* question you'd see that I already tried that. (While it fixed the alignment, it somehow caused my custom icon to be lost.)

Answer (score 0):

Using this worked for me:

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         searchView.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Gravity.END));
     }
});
```